# for loop embedded in merge

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a question on the forum and someone very kindly provided me with an answer. However, I can't get my head around the code at the **end** of the following code snippet:

**data**

```
#data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'business': ['FX','a','CR'],
 'A/L': ['A','A','L'],
 'Company': ['207','1','2']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data
```

**filter**

```
#filter
f = {'business':['FX','FX','IR','IR','CR'],
 'A/L':['A','L','A','L','#'],
 'Company':['207','#','#','207','#']}
filter = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
filter
```

**cols**

```
#cols
cols = filter.columns
```

**filter final**

```
filter['wild'] = filter.apply(lambda x: tuple(col for col in cols
                                         if x[col] != '#'), axis=1)
```

**code I am finding difficult**

```
result = pd.concat([data.merge(df, on=k, suffixes=('', '_y'),
                           right_index=True)[cols]
                for k, df in filter.groupby('wild')]).sort_index()
```

Comment: `k` is the value of column `wild`. It is the value of column wild.

Iterating over a groupby object yields two values.

The first one – your k is the item of the column(s) you have grouped by.
The second value – your df – is the data for this value in the group that corresponds to this particular item. So you join on the values of `wild`, item per item.

Comment: thanks. I can't understand how merge knows how to join the data. can you point me in the direction of some documentation that explains this ? I could not find it in the official documentation.

Comment: You're welcome. And sure. Have a look here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/03.07-Merge-and-Join.ipynb

Comment: thanks for the link. However, I can still now find out what [cols] does. Is it part of pd.merge or pd.concat in the statement above ?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE so that we can replicate this. Post the minimal neccessary code and the data – not as images but rather as text inline in your post.

Comment: And specifically regarding `[cols]`: Where exactly is `cols` defined? This is not in your code line...

Comment: I have provide the code sample for data, filter,cols and filter

Comment: In general it would be helpful if you described, what you want to achieve with the filtered merge. The code «filter final» doesn't seem to do anything, at least for your sample data. `[cols]` in your merge removes all the columns from `df` that are present in both dataframes (`df` and `data`) that you merge and concat. This you can try yourself by removing `[cols]` from your code.